# Any command in my terminal that exits with non-zero code closes my terminal window

Tags: linux, bash, macos

Any command in my terminal that exits with non-zero code closes my terminal window. I was told that perhaps I have `set -e` set in some bash script somewhere that my terminal sources.

I have checked `.bash_profile` / `.bashrc` / `.profile` and it doesn't look like `set -e` is in there.

Would there be any other obvious culprits?

Here is [the output](https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/523a75aca385362e11f9a286e9ec26db) of `bash -lx`.

I would like to stop my terminal window from closing every time a command fails (exits with non-zero code).

It looks like [my problem is here](https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/523a75aca385362e11f9a286e9ec26db#file-lx-log-L508).

Comment: put `exec bash -e` at the end of `.bashrc`

Comment: thanks what will that accomplish btw?

Comment: What do you have in Terminal > Preferences > Shell > "When the shell exists"?

Comment: @SiKing it's happening for more than 1 terminal type, both Iterm2 and my Webstorm terminal emulator have the same problem, so that's a hint.

Comment: @IporSircer I think you mean `exec bash +e`. However, that's likely to source whatever file is running `set -e` in the first place.

Comment: Run `bash -lx`; the output should show `set -e` being run and give you some indication of which file it appears in.

Comment: @chepner: No, i mean `bash -e`. (version 4.4.12)

Comment: @IporSircer He already has the `-e` option set; he's trying to turn it off. Your suggestion just ensures that it gets turned on regardless of what occurs previously in the configuration files.

Comment: @chepner: He wants to close the terminal on any non-zero exitcode. `bash -e` do this, `bash +e` doesn't do this. Try yourself!

Comment: "At first this was a bit funny... but now it's getting old". That sounds to me like he's trying to *stop* the terminal from exiting on a non-zero exit status.

Comment: I am going to put my `bash -lx` output into a file on github gist

Comment: OK I added the output of `bash -lx` to the question.

Comment: @chepner thanks, you helped me solve the problem, I added an answer, let me know if it makes sense, apparently `bash -lx` sends its output to stderr no stdout which is a bit strange.

Comment: this is a beautiful question and does not deserve any downvotes and there is now an answer to the question which is also beautiful.

Comment: The `-x` option is for debugging, so standard error is suitable.

Comment: That is true good point. What is also true is that this question deserves not a downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so indeed, it was a wayward `set -e` that caused my trouble.

The way I found the `set -e` was using `bash -lx`...

The best thing to do would be to use:

`bash -lx > lx.log 2>&1`

then open that log file and do a search for `set`...

once you find that wayward `set -e` you can remove that line and your problem should be gone!

In my case, the `set -e` was in a file that .bash_profile sources, but the line was not in .bash_profile itself.